# Why extern "C" still cannot remove name mangling in the following case

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, name-decoration

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK MTest
}
```

Using depends , I found there is still name mangling even using `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to get truly undecorated names with __declspec(dllexport) is to export them with the __cdecl calling convention. CALLBACK becomes __stdcall, which decorates the "C" form of the name with a leading _ and trailing @bytes.

Otherwise you can use a .DEF file, which is a pain. Another MSVC specific way is to embed a /[EXPORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5(v=VS.100).aspx) directive into the object file (or pass it as a explicit linker setting)

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:ExportSymbol=DecoratedName");
```

For some reason the `=` part of the directive is not listed in the help

Comment: I thought that would be self evident. The best reason to dislike them is they are a hard to find point of failure.

Comment: I generate mine as part of a build script, but I take your point.

Answer (score 4):

That's name decoration rather than mangling. You should declare the undecorated name in a DEF file and then you'll get the behaviour you are seeking.

Comment: @user Actually Chris Becke points out that you can use a #pragma, or cdecl. Personally I don't see any problems with a DEF file but I guess everyone has their own preferred way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Not being much of a visual C++ programmer the first thought that occurs to me is ... "do any of those macros LRESULT or CALLBACK introduce the standard calling convention?" Do the mangled names have @NUMBER_OF_BYTES_OF_PARAMATER_LIST or characters depicting the actual types appended to them?